# Failing at getting Laravel Running on Windows

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to get a laravel programming enviroment up to finish my masters' degree project but I can't get this to work no matter how hard I try.

I've followed various tutorials but the last one I've tried has been http://sherriflemings.blogspot.com.es/2015/03/laravel-homestead-on-windows-8.html
and I think I got somewhere but I get the following error trying to initialize vagrant

Vagrant up error:

[image: Vagrant up error]

and I've confirmed that the file C:\Users\Administrator\homestead\Homestead\scripts\homestead.rb is available and permissions are correct.

Also In the error I see C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa (Errno::ENOENT)
but I have other routes difined in my Homestead.yaml

Is there any other way I can run homstead of have a Laravel development enviromet?
What tutorial would you recommend to get this up and running?

Comment: Do you really have the id_rsa file?

Comment: Oh now I see what's going on, the file homestead.rb is complainingh about a missing file, the way the output was structured I thought it was complaining the homestead.rb file was missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I totally agree with the previous answer, I wanted to provide some more information about your state.

There is no need to check if the `homestead.rb` exists at that stage. Because it is already the running code and informing you about the problem that it can't fix by herself.

That is also not a route problem (to tell the truth; the provided information under 'sites' key of `Homestead.yaml` is not about routes. You are listing the projects inside your homestead virtual machine there. One site per project is generally enough. Like:

```
-sites:
    - map: foo.com
    - to: /home/vagrant/Code/Foo/public
```

Your homestead.rb file is blocked while running because the created virtual machine's operating system needs something to trust your code working using `ssh`. And one of the ways of achieving that is using a public key - private key pair (also used by homestead). It looks like you don't have a pair. And the script running can't access the public key: AKA id_rsa.

Answer (score 1):

You should [generate key](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key) to make it work. So, you will have two files 
`id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` in your `C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/` folder.

Comment: I had both files but in "ssh" instead of ".ssh", although I had specified another directory in my .yaml file wich didn't apply.So anyway I renamed the directory and now I get another error

$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code

Should I provide my config file?

Comment: If you're new to Homestead and Laravel, I'd recommend you try to install everything using official guide without renaming folders etc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead - I use it every time I need to install Homestead and never had any problem. )

Comment: Thanks for the tip Alexey Mezenin, I was under the impression the official guide wouldn't be very windows friendly but I'll give it a shot! It's motivating to hear you had no problems!